# Chart Shared Tooltip Title

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart, kendo-tooltip

So I have a chart which has a shared tooltip across multiple series. This is a time-based series, with categories of each hour in a day. I'm able to correctly format the labels in the chart just fine.

The issue I have is that I can't seem to change the title of the tooltip. It's always formatted as m/ddd/yyyy. I've tried changing the template, changing the format, etc, but because it's shared those only seem to be applied to the values and not the category title itself.

Is this possible to do? Can I create a custom tooltip instead of using the chart tooltip builder? I've been trying to do this, but have not gotten it to work successfully yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I needed to set the `SharedTemplate` instead of the `Template`.